# Convert symbolic links to hard links in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, symlink

I want to convert soft links to hard links recursively in a directory in windows batch script. I have been able to do this in linux but I am not quite sure about how to get this done in a batch file. Can someone let me know what I should do to get this done ?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to dig a bit more and I think /L would help in copying symbolic links. I am not sure if I am right though. I am trying to copy the files in my local machine to a remote host. 
I am doing copy /L < my local path > 
Am I approaching this the right way?

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not usually a sensible thing to do, since symbolic links and hard links have somewhat different semantics.  I assume you're dealing with a special case?

Comment: Hi Harry, I understand that this is not a good thign to do but I need to get this done because our servers don't copy symlinks but this is needed on my side :(

Answer (score 2):

I see two methods of converting symbolic links to hard links:

- Using [NTFSLinksView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html) utility.

  ```
  @echo off
  set listfile="%temp%\links%random%.html"
  start /wait ntfslinksview /shtml %listfile% /folder "." /subfolders

  for /f "delims=>< tokens=5,9" %%a in ('
       find ">Symbolic Link<" %listfile%
  ') do (
      ren "%%a" "%%~nxa.bak"
      mklink /h "%%~fa" "%%b" && del "%%a.bak" || (ren "%%a.bak" "%%~nxa" & echo    %%a)
  )
  del %listfile%
  pause
  ```
- Using the built-in `dir` command
  (this is a simplified code that won't work on files with `!` in the name).

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "eol=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /AL /b "."') do (
      for /f "eol=* tokens=2 delims=>" %%b in ('dir "%%a" ^| find "<SYMLINK>"') do (
          set "target=%%b"
          set "target=!target: %%~nxa =!"
          set "target=!target:~0,-1!"
          for /f "eol=* delims=[ tokens=2" %%c in ("!target!") do (
              ren "%%a" "%%~nxa.bak"
              mklink /h "%%~fa" "%%c" ^
              && (del "%%a.bak") ^
              || (ren "%%a.bak" "%%~nxa" & echo    %%a)
          )
      )
  )
  pause
  ```